# java null pointer exception

Tags: java, stream, arrays

I'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` at   `while ((len = in.read(buf , 0 , buf.length)) >= 0)` in following method:

```
public void copy(String  src, File dst) throws IOException {

  InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(src); 
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1012];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf , 0 , buf.length)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
            buf = null;
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
```

I'm not getting the coz.I will be thankful if I get the solution.thanks in advance.......

Comment: If you set 'buf' to null... it will be null.

Answer (score 10):

You set

```
buf = null;
```

at the first iteration, at the second buf.length throws the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2):

Because you set `buf = null;` after the first iteration of the loop. It will fail on the second run of the while-loop.

Answer (score 2):

I see two possible NullPointer here:

1. The `buf=null;`, which definitly causes a NullPointerException on the second iteration.
2. getResourceAsStream will return `null` if `src` wasn't found.

Answer (score 1):

`buf = null;` inside your while loop is causing the problem, try commenting that line.

Answer (score -1):

You need to something like below inside the loop:

```
buf = new byte[1012];
```

Or you could remove the `buf = null` entirely.

Comment: A removal of buf=null will be sufficient